# Why does installing Kubuntu-desktop prompt me to remove "lpr"?

Tags: kubuntu, software-installation, desktop-environments

I want to install the full kubuntu desktop from the software centre, when I hit install it pops out a window that says "To install kubuntu-desktop, these items must be removed:" with this package listed below.

I don't really know much about this package but I want to know **the reason** why kubuntu-desktop wants to remove it. Also I wanna make sure that removing this package won't affect unity's features or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lpr` is the BSD print spooler and utilities. It typically isn't used in the various *buntu flavors (Ubuntu, Ubuntu Gnome, Ubuntu Studio, Kubuntu, Xubuntu, and Lubuntu) anymore. A newer variant, included in the `cups-bsd` package, provides the same functionality and includes support for Internet Printing Protocol.

The package `kubuntu-desktop` recommends the package `cups-bsd`. It replaces the `lpr` package -- that's why the package manager wants to remove it.

As to why you have `lpr` installed now, hard to say. Given that `cups-bsd` is standard across the *buntu flavors, I'd say you're safe to proceed.

Comment: okay thanks alot :D actually I've already installed kbuntu a while ago. I have one more question though; why can't I have both? Anyways thanks alot :D

Comment: The packaging details for `cups-bsd` indicate that the package manager should remove `lpr` if it's installed. Both packages provide binaries with the same names and stored in the same locations. They can't both be installed at the same time for that reason.

Comment: "same names in same location"!! it makes sense to me now. Thank you so much :D